# What is Wrist Goal & Arm Pole for?

Tags: animation, rigging

i just recently started to learn with Blender , specifically animations and rigging. So i went to the internet and downloaded few things to see how are they done.
I downloaded this model of Fps hands which are rigged and i found 4 objects i know nothing about.

[image: image of objects]

From my experience i'd say they have something to do with Inverse Kinematics, but they dont seem to be doing anything whenever i try to rotate them or move them.
thanks in advance.

EDIT: the file => [link to file](https://filebin.net/c48ayj9jkluzdxw6/fpsarms.fbx?t=oasa52pj)

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the file. If you could attach it, it would help others see what you're talking about so they can better help. Judging just from the names though, it seems the wrist goals would be IK targets (hand positions/orientations) and the arm poles would be pole targets (direction of the elbows).

Comment: Did that ,sorry for that @TheTrueJard